# Can I perform concurrent actions on an ISO 7816 card?

Tags: concurrency, smartcard, apdu, emv, iso-7816-4

I know that ISO 7816 compliant cards, like modern EMV Chip and PIN cards, are typically used in a command response scenario, the reader sends a command APDU to the card, and the latter sends a response.
However, can the card perform concurrent activities, such as perform any dummy action while it waits for a command from the reader, or does it have to wait passively?

Comment: My answer to the [security forum question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240895/can-iso-7816-emv-based-smart-card-handle-interrupts/241071#241071) still holds.

Comment: The terminal can do parallel processing in some cases, but not the card.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The card does the action only based on the APDU command request. For a request, a response is expected, and in most cases in a sequence too. To say, you cannot do a GET PO before SELECT, you cannot request a GEN AC before GET PO.

But I am curious what the 'concurrent activities' possible, could you think aloud?

Comment: I want to see if the card can keep incrementing a counter while waiting for a command APDU from the reader. And when it receives this command, it stops counting and prepares the response to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

What the main reason behind that?
I think u cannot  do parallel  action on the card because each command u r sending affect the current card status.